# Solving a 2 equation / 2 variables system with trigonometric components

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

If anybody wants to have fun solving trigonometrics systems, I am highy interested. :)

I've got the following system  to solve, which includes trigonometric functions.

$x_{0}$, $x_{1}$, $y_{0}$, and $y_{1}$,  are known.

I'm looking for $\theta_{0}$ and $\theta_{1}$ and I am stuck...
Any idea ?

$$ \begin{align}[x_{1}\cos(\theta_{1}) - y_{1}\sin(\theta_{1}) ] - [x_{0}\cos(\theta_{0}) - y_{0}\sin(\theta_{0})] &= (x_{1}-x_{0})^2 + (y_{1}-y_{0})^2 \\
 [x_{1}\sin(\theta_{1}) + y_{1}\cos(\theta_{1}) ] - [x_{0}\sin(\theta_{0}) + y_{0}\cos(\theta_{0})] &= 0\end{align} $$

Any help will be gratefully accepted!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you have the first equation correct?  If it is from a physical system and $x$ and $y$ have the length unit, then the lhs is a length while the rhs is an area.

Comment: Originally, all left and right terms are divided by the square root of the right term.

assuming the denominator cannot be null, I've multiplied the temrs on each side.

Hence, $$ 0 \times sqrt ( (x_{1}-x_{0})^2 + (y_{1}-y_{0})^2 ) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_i = r_i\cos\alpha_i$ and $y_i = r_i\sin\alpha_i$, the two equations becomes $$r_1\cos(\alpha_1+\theta_1) - r_0\cos(\alpha_0+\theta_0) = (x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2$$ $$r_1\sin(\alpha_1+\theta_1) = r_0\sin(\alpha_0+\theta_0).$$  The second equation can further lead to $$r_1^2\cos^2(\alpha_1+\theta_1) = (r_1^2-r_0^2)+r_0^2\cos^2(\alpha_0+\theta_0).$$  Then you can eliminate $\cos(\alpha_1+\theta_1)$ from the first equation and solving a quadratic equation of $\cos(\alpha_0+\theta_0)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !

i was trying with complex exponentials, and the same variable changing we were using for integral calculation, while I just could switch to polar coordinates :)